# How to remove sticky color from iron box

Tags: clothing, paint

Due to mishandle some color of cloth sticked to the iron box surface . Now i cant use because that color sticks on cloth I iron . So give some hacks to remove that color from iron box .

Comment: If you are talking about color on the sole of a [clothes iron](//en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clothes_iron), then I would suggest clarifying that in both title and text. If possible, I would also include picture of the stain, to help us distinguish what kind of surface we're talking about.

Comment: Ya , that sounds great @holroy . You better post the picture .Thank You

Comment: Ehh, I can't post a picture of your stain. And you can edit your post b clicking on the edit link below post.

Comment: Got it @holroy ,I will post as soon as possible..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why color sticks to the iron box is because the temperature of the box would have been beyond the melting temperature of the fabric that was ironed. And over a few more ironing sessions, this will collect dust and other colors and wold have turned black.

One way of removing the color off the iron box is to allow it to heat to a moderate level and using a wooden stick, try scraping off the color.

Answer (score 0):

I used to work as a t-shirt screen printer, and when we wanted to remove some ink we would use acetone.  This is a common ingredient in nail-polish remover.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using Sodium bicarbonate (baking soda). When the iron is slightly hot, put some baking soda on a piece of wet cotton and rub the surface. I tried it before and it worked.